# Magento: How to programatically set the base image to the first image in the list

Tags: image, magento

## The problem

### Current Situation

I'm having a problem with a third-party ioncube loader encoded feedloader plugin which is no longer supported by the original author (since they went tits-up) and instead of putting in two weeks to completely write it from scratch, I've decided to fix the problems it has after the import has run.

### Compatibility

The only problem is: I want to write this using functions in the Mage library, not rely on a few custom queries that might break in the next update of Magento or whenever I change something in the database (I just want to get to know Magento's core functions better I guess)

### Problem Diagnosis

The import does nearly everything correct, except from setting the base image (the small and thumbnail image are set correctly), as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: The first and only image has not been selected as default Base Image]

The actual record in the database is missing for that image.. (so tempted to fix it with a query, but I won't.. I'm going to keep looking for an elegant solution)

Also, the function $product->getMediaGalleryImages() doesn't return any images, so I can't use the solution as suggested by @SKV over at [Set Base Image Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954265/set-base-image-programmatically) .. unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: use `getMediaGallery` instead of `getMediaGalleryImages`. See my answer. I've tested and it works.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$productId = 1;
//load the product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
//get all images
$mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
//if there are images
if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
    //loop through the images
    foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){
        //set the first image as the base image
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('image'=>$image['file']), 0);
        //stop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to try this myself, unfortunately some high-prio fixes have come up for another project.. I will try to do this later today. As soon as I have confirmed this I will mark this as the correct solution. Thank you!!

Comment: might be years old but this was very useful to me today

Comment: Base image working,  May i know of small image and thumbnail image?

Comment: @Rathinam replace `image` with `small_image` or `thumbnail` in the `updateAttribtues` call.

Comment: @Marius $productId = 1; How can i add multiple product ids, If i try this $productId = array(3, 21, 24, 42, 74); its not working. error : https://snag.gy/F19p8v.jpg

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution I eventually used in 'shell/fix_images.php':

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('abstract.php');

class Mage_Shell_Updater extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_imported', 1); // attribute added by importer
        $c=0;
        foreach($products as $p) {
            $pid = $p->getId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
            $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
            if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
                foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){
                    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
                    ->updateAttributes(array($pid), array('image'=>$image['file']), 0);
                    $c++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        echo($c . " product(s) updated.");
    }

}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Updater();
$shell->run();
```

If anyone should use this, be sure to remove the 'addAttributeToFilter' from your own Mage method chain.. If you are going to run this as a standalone script (without disabling the realtime indexing first), add this code at the beginning of run():

```
    $pCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
    foreach ($pCollection as $process) {
        $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)->save();
    }
```

at the end of run():

```
    foreach ($pCollection as $process) {
        $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();
    }
```

Also, the abstract.php is from Mage_Shell, usually located in the /shell/ directory in the root of your Magento installation.

Comment: What would I change to set all the images?  Hundreds of my imported images are being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my problem i have set the images for the enabled grouped product. I have set the last image as the base,small and thumbnail image.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter("type_id",array("eq","grouped"))
                  ->addAttributeToFilter("status",array("eq","1"));
foreach($collection as $tmpProduct) {
  $sku = $tmpProduct->getSku();
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                 ->loadByAttribute("sku",$sku);
  $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                 ->load($product->getId())
                 ->getMediaGalleryImages();
  $checkImage =  Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'catalog'.DS.'product'.DS.$product->getImage();

  if( $product->getImage()!=''  && is_file($checkImage)) {
    continue; // do nothing
  } else {
    if($_images) {
      $baseImage = '';
      foreach($_images as $_image) {
        $baseImage = $_image->getFile();
      }
      $groupedImagePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'catalog'.DS.'product'.DS.$baseImage;
      $product->setMediaGallery(
                  array('images'=>array (),
                        'values'=>array ()));
      $product->addImageToMediaGallery(
                  $groupedImagePath,
                  array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'),
                  false,
                  false);   
      Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')
          ->remove($product->getId(),$baseImage);
      $product->save();  
      echo "<br>$sku has selected image <br>";
} } }
```

Comment: You appear to be setting the media gallery to empty arrays and then adding the image. If there are multiple images saved with a product, will this remove all but the last one?