# Identifying Variables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, magento

I am trying to run the following code on my magento database:

```
    UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
    AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
    AND ev.attribute_ID = '76'
    AND mgv.position = 1;
```

Before I run this i need to identify the ev.attribute_ID = '76'   (The 76 is different for each install)

What would I need to use to discover what that number is in my particular install?

(I am trying to update the images in my magento store to display in mass.)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your images programmatically.
Read that answer Marius wrote: [How to programatically set the base image to the first image in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153891/magento-how-to-programatically-set-the-base-image-to-the-first-image-in-the-lis)

It's not a good idea to use direct sql queries in Magento...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know `entity_type_code` and `attribute_code` of your attribute to generally get the proper `attribute_id` of your particular installs.

If you already know that codes, you can use something like this, for example:

```
$entity_type_code = 'catalog_product';
$attribute_code = 'name';
$attributeId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute($entity_type_code, $attribute_code)
    ->getId();
```

### How to identify the codes of an attribute_id

If you only have an `attribute_id`, but don't know where/how to get that codes, here's how:

If you check the table definition of `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, you'll find that `attribute_id` is a foreign key referring to `eav_attribute.attribute_id`.

Hence, check the `eav.attribute` table to find the record having your `attribute_id == 76`.

The found record does contain the general `attribute_code` value you're after.

If you're sure, that the `entity_type_id` is the *same* for all your particular installs, then you don't even need to get the `entity_type_code` and can stop here. Just pass the `entity_type_id` of the found record as 1st param to the `getAttribute()`call above.

If the `entity_type_id` *differs* in your particular installs, then you still need to get the `entity_type_code`.

Grab the value of `entity_type_id` of the found record and search the `eav_entity_type` table for this `entity_type_id` (`entity_type_id` is a foreign key referring to `eav_entity_type.entity_type_id`). The found record contains the value of your general `entity_type_code`, valid for all your installs.

---

That being said, for BC reasons I'd always recommend to prefer using Magento methods wherever possible.